# Timeline how to force event to display precisely with hour instead of expand to full day

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-5

I'm working with fullcalendar, and I need one piece of functionality. I'll explain with an example using the demo.

Here is a codePen provided by [ADyson](http://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/mdBoaPo?editors=001)

That codepen was created by following this instructions. Go to the [demo](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timeline-standard-view-demo) and click on `edit in codePen` and replace the properties events with (you may need to adjust the day if you're seeing this in the future) :

```
[{"resourceId":"a","title":"event 4","start":"2022-01-17T07:20:00+00:00","end":"2022-01-17T09:50:00+00:00"}]
```

On the day view we can see that the event render precisely depending of the time specified. Even, and that's what I want, if it doesn't fit the grid

Ok in day view:

[image]

But on the Month view, the event visually expand to take the full day of 17/01.

What I see in month view:

[image]

What I'd like to see instead would be something like that (edited image) :

What I want in month view:

[image]

Is it possible to disable the expand functionality and let the event display only depending on the time ? I've looked for an option on the official documentation but found none.

> (Context) Why do I need this ?
> Because if I have two events on the same resource, let'say 8h-12h and 14h-18h. With the default rendering in month view those two events would be vertically aligned. With what I want to do, they'll be horizontally aligned.
> This let me create an overview where it is really easy to see if a resource have two events on the same time.

Phase 2 debugging :

As discussed with ADyson it seems that it is impossible to do this kind of view using only settings. But I have done a bit of debugging in fullcalendar and I have found out that at some point, when I render a view with a slotDuration set to day or bigger, the `start` and `end` of my event are respectively set to the `start of day` and `end of day`. I just can't figure out where this conversion is done.

Any insight, even if I have to change some code in fullcalendar would be useful.

Comment: I made a demo with your data and I don't get the same screenshots. You seem to have used a different reasource, and because you've missed off the times from the top, it's difficult to understand exactly what we're seeing, and what you're expecting it to be instead. Make sure the screenshots match the supplied sample data, and also let us know if you've customised anything in the fullcalendar settings. Here's my demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/mdBoaPo?editors=001

Comment: Or are you just asking how to make it show the times as well as the title, in all cases (rather than anything about the width etc)? It wasn't fully clear. Please edit the question to give a more complete example and more precise explanation of the problem.

Comment: I'll edit my post, providing your link, we can see my trouble with this example and make new screenshot to explain myself better. I'm not asking how to show time "in" the title of the event.

Comment: Thanks. It's much clearer now. You can't have what you're showing because the smallest "time slot" in the month view (by default) is 1 day. That means that's the smallest amount of time that fullCalendar will take into account when rendering the event. It assumes you're not interested in that level of detail when viewing over a larger time period.

Comment: However, you can customise the view settings and set the `slotDuration` to a smaller time-frame, so you get more granularity. That comes at the cost of it using more width on the calendar, so you have to decide what your users are really going to want. The whole point of having different views available (e.g. month, week, day) is effectively to "zoom in" or "zoom out" depending how much detail you need. You get a very similar effect on products such as Google Calendar. It makes a lot of sense from a UX perspective, in terms of how much detail people can absorb at once.

Comment: See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-settings, https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slotDuration and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slotLabelInterval to help you customise the views to your liking if you want to, though.

Comment: Thanks for the update with a bit of context. The answer is the same though - you can customise the slotDuration (and related settings) for that view. Although with them vertically aligned you can still "see if a resource have two events on at the same time" anyway - you can make it display the end time of the event too, if you need more detail in the description to help with that.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, before posting I have already tested to play with duration, slotDuration and slotLabeIterval and I couldn't get the view I want. With your answer, I now know that it's impossible using only settings. But I'm sure it's possible if I edit myself some code in fullcalendar ; I haven't found where I should look... yet.

Comment: You could try that, but it'll be a pretty fundamental re-write of the rendering and positioning engine I would think - not a trivial task at all, even assuming you can figure out where the relevant code exists within the source. And then you'll be stuck when you want to upgrade to a newer version. It's a maintenance nightmare, I really wouldn't burden yourself with forking the library just for the sake of this.

Comment: So either you have to understand and accept the UX reason for having a zoomed-out month view (which you could perhaps enhance a bit by showing event end times by default), and just let your users view the detail by going into the weeks and days to see the exact layout, or you go with something like this: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/mdBgrXZ?editors=001

Comment: `I have found out that at some point, when I render a view with a slotDuration set to day or bigger, the start and end of my event are respectively set to the start of day and end of day`...it's not that they're set to that internally, it's just that they're drawn like that. As you've noticed, a slot duration of 1 days or more causes fullcalendar to ignore any time component smaller than the slot. If you don't like it, raise a feature request with the fullcalendar team, but presumably, as I've alluded to above, there are some UX reasons for doing that.

Comment: I know, there are valid reasons for the actual behavior. Hell I'd like to stay on a standard version if possible. But this is a mandatory requirement I'm asked for, so I have to go to the bottom of this. Two facts makes me think that this is possible. First on a view with a slot duration by hour the event to fit the grid. Second ; when I debug in `TimelineLaneSlicer` I can see my event, but the hours are set to `00:00:00`, so there is something somewhere that internally change the event. But with only a few hours in it, I can't define precisely what it is or even if it'll actually help me.

Comment: I'll spend some more hours on it before giving up. Anyway, thanks for your answers, you've actually help me being certain that I can't do anything by settings only and you have solid arguments against this evolution, that I can use if I give up. :-)

Comment: All requirements are optional, if you can convince the people making it mandatory that going ahead with it is more trouble than it's worth. Try negotiating a compromise - I've suggested a couple already.